# (Excel) function to return specific value from a table based on conditions

Tags: r, excel, powerbi

I have the following data:

```
store   location   mass   target
1       1 (Ams)    45     ?
2       5 (Ber)    500    ?
3       8 (Mar)    1003   ?
```

In this last column *target* I would like to have a value from the table:

```
              location 
 mass range    1       5     8 
 0 - 350       3       4     5
 > 351         6       7     8
```

So the target column should contain the values, 3, 7, 8 in the first three rows.

I tried to use the function INDEX() but did not work out.. If anyone knows how to do this in R or in PowerBI that would also help me. Thanks!

In R the example is reproducable by using:

```
structure(list(Store = 1:3, Location = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L
), .Label = c("08-Mar", "1 Ams", "5 Ber"), class = "factor"), 
Mass = c(1000L, 800L, 500L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                  -3L))
```

and

```
structure(list(X = structure(1:2, .Label = c("0 - 350", "351 - 1000"
), class = "factor"), X1 = c(3L, 6L), X5 = c(4L, 7L), X8 = c(5L, 
8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: For R, can you make this post reproducible by adding data using `dput` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reform your table 2 then you could use `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions as below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In R, we require a bit of pre-processing before we can actually merge the two tables since the data is not in a standard format. Assuming the two tables are called `df1` and `df2` respectively, we `separate` the data into different columns for `Location` in `df1` and `X` in `df2`. We also add additional `"X"` character in `df1` so that it matches the column name of `df2`. We bring data in long format using `gather` in `df2` and use `fuzzy_left_join` to merge by number range.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  separate(Location, into = c("Loc1", "Loc2"), sep = "\\s+|-", convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Loc1 = paste0("X", Loc1)) %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(df2 %>%
                separate(X, into = c("start", "end"), convert = TRUE) %>%
                gather(key, Target, starts_with("X")),
          by = c("Loc1" = "key", "Mass" = "start", "Mass" = "end"), 
          match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`))

#  Store Loc1 Loc2 Mass start  end key Target
#1     1   X1  Ams 1000   351 1000  X1      6
#2     2   X5  Ber  800   351 1000  X5      7
#3     3   X8  Mar   45     0  350  X8      5
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Store = 1:3, Location = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L
), .Label = c("08-Mar", "1 Ams", "5 Ber"), class = "factor"), 
Mass = c(1000, 800, 45)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(X = structure(1:2, .Label = c("0 - 350", "351 - 1000"
), class = "factor"), X1 = c(3L, 6L), X5 = c(4L, 7L), X8 = c(5L, 
8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```